# How to revert to default form for content type

Tags: content-type, 2016, feature-activation, edit-form

I added a new feature and inside `FeatureActived` wrote following code to open my custom task form whenever user clicks on task title.

```
SPContentType myTask = web.ContentTypes["Workflow Task"];  
myTask.EditFormUrl = "_layouts/mytask.aspx";  
myTask.DisplayFormUrl = "_layouts/mytask.aspx";  
myTask.Update(true);
```

This code is working fine. Problem is I want to revert to default out of the box form but even if I comment these lines and re-deploy solution OR disable feature in "site collection features" OR retract solution, clicking on task title still takes the user to my custom form.

How can I revert to default form?

Comment: Write the same code in the feature deactivated event. However, update the Eidt and Display Form Urls with default values.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it but the question is what are default values?

Comment: I don't remember. But you can try to find those in a new site collection.

Comment: Ok on feature deactivation I simply wrote `myTask.EditFormUrl = ""` and it fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: ok, great......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following PowerShell to reset the values:

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://sharepointurl"
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Workflow Task"]
$ct.DisplayFormUrl = $null
$ct.EditFormUrl = $null
$ct.Update()
$web.Dispose()
```